# Remove "\n" from a string, but leave the actual linebreaks?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, textbox

I'm doing a Python course, and the current assignment is to take information from a database, add it to a textbox, and then create an HTML file from the content inside the textbox.

Everything works perfectly, with breaks in the lines exactly how I typed them into the database. The only problem is that "{{" and "}}" get added around the text after it's retrieved from the database. So I turn the text into a string and slice that stuff off with [3:-4]. But then, since it's now a string, it now literally writes "\n" into the text when it's inputted into the textbox.

Is there anyway to slice off the brackets, NOT include the "\n" text, but still keep the linebreaks?

Here's what the textbox displays before I turn it into a string and slice:

{{This is my text!
It looks very clean because it has linebreaks.
Sweet!}}

And after I make it a string and cut the ends off:

This is my text!\n\nThe brackets are gone but now you can see linebreak code.\n\nLame!

Can I have the best of both worlds? Here's my code:

```
    # Grabs info from database on button click
def getContent(self):
    c.execute("SELECT HTML FROM Content WHERE conName ='{}'".format(self.contentBox.get()))
    fetch = (c.fetchall())
    return str(fetch)[3:-4]

    # Inserts content into textbox
def setContent(self):
    self.clear()
    combo = self.getContent()
    self.text_body.insert(END,combo)
```

Comment: Don't use `str.format` directly or you'll be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: The only way to access the database in my script is to choose one of five options from a readonly combobox.

Comment: @NathanR An attacker can easily modify the combobox on the browser side. Never trust the client.

Comment: A Text(box) automatically wraps, i.e. add line breaks.  Pass wrap="none" to the Text class when you create the instance.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! For now, it's just a simple exercise to learn how to combine a tkinter GUI with SQLite3. None of it is going online, and the database is full of silly things I made up.

Comment: I used to not have a "wrap=" at all, but added "wrap=WORD" because the textbox kept cutting words in half.

Comment: Get into the habit anyway so that you automatically do it right when it matters. Plus you'll probably get extra marks. And I may be wrong but I think you just have to say `c.execute("SELECT HTML FROM Content WHERE conName ={}", self.contentBox.get())` and it'll interpolate the query correctly for you. It's even shorter than doing it manually.

Comment: And you do realize that the fetch statement can return multiple records which might also be part of the problem.  Post the output displayed in the console when "combo" is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that your actual string has 2 '\' in it.
Your actual string after formatting it is:
this is my text!\\n\\nThe brackets are gone but now you can see linebreak code.\\n\\nLame!
the extra \ means that the \n should actually be printed and not referred to as a line break.

Comment: Hmmm, weird... any idea how it might have gotten there? and how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that you are getting data from the database back as a list of lists (though the inner list may be a single element containing the HTML) You start to cause problems when you either insert that data literally into a widget, or if you use `str` to convert that data to a string.

The reason you see curly braces, for example, is that the the text widget doesn't know how to display a list of lists, so it uses curly braces to delineate list items (there's a good reason, but it's a long explanation). Those curly braces aren't in the actual data from the database, they get added when you try to add a list to the text widget.

The proper solution is to take your database data in it's raw form (list of lists or list of HTML elements) and convert it to a string intelligently. You will then no longer need to trim braces or convert newlines, or do any other sort of hack to make your data look right.

For example, if you want a newline between each row of data, and a space between each column of data (assuming you're getting back more than one column), you can insert the data like this:

```
def getContent(self):
    c.execute("SELECT HTML FROM Content WHERE conName ='{}'".format(self.contentBox.get()))
    fetch = (c.fetchall())
    return  # return a list of lists

def setContent(self):
    self.clear()
    combo = self.getContent()
    for row in combo:
        # convert list of columns into a string, by joining
        # each column with a space
        text = " ".join(row) 

        # write this row, and a newline, to the text widget
        self.text_body.insert(END, text + "\n")
```

This may not be the precise solution for you since I don't know exactly what the data coming back from the database is. The point is that you need to know what type of data the database call is returning (a list of lists), and to do an intelligent job of turning that data into a string.

You could also choose to create a separate function that converts the data, or you could do the conversion in `getContent`. The important thing is to understand what format your data in in (a list or rows from the database), and what format it needs to be in (string), and do a proper conversion after fetching the data and before passing the data to the text widget.