# How to remove the literal string "\n" (not newlines) from a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, tr

I'm pulling some data from a database and one of the strings I'm getting back is in one line and contains multiple instances of the string `\n`. These are not newline characters; they are literally the string `\n`, i.e. backslash+en, or hex 5C 6E.

I've tried using sed and tr to remove them however they don't seem recognize the string and don't effect the variable at all. This has been a difficult problem to search for on google as all the results I get back are about how to remove newline characters from strings which is not what I need.

How can I remove these strings from my variable in bash?

Example data:

`\n\nCreate a URL where the client can point their web browser to.  This URL should test the following IP addresses and ports for connectivity.`

Example failed command:

```
echo "$someString" | tr '\\n' ''
```

Operating system: Solaris 10

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974182/remove-n-from-a-string-but-leave-the-actual-linebreaks) - Except this is in python

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input data, and show us what you tried?

Comment: `echo "one\\ntwo" | perl -wpe 's/\\n//g'`.  (The `\\n` in input is to create such a string.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you just didn't escape the `\` correctly in the replacement when using `sed`. Also note that `tr` is not well-suited for this task.
Finally, if you want to replace `\n` in a *variable*, then **Pattern substitution** (a form of **Parameter Expansion**) is your best option.

To replace `\n` in a variable, you can use Bash pattern substitution:

```
$ text='hello\n\nthere\nagain'
$ echo ${text//\\n/}
hellothereagain
```

To replace `\n` in standard input, you can use `sed`:

```
$ echo 'hello\n\nthere\nagain' | sed -e 's/\\n//g'
hellothereagain
```

Notice the `\` escaped in the pattern as `\\` in both examples.

Answer (score 3):

The `tr` utility will only work with single characters, transliterating them from one set of characters to another. This is not the tool you want.

With `sed`:

```
newvar="$( sed 's/\\n//g' <<<"$var" )"
```

The only thing worth noting here is the escaping of the `\` in `\n`.  I'm using a here-string (`<<<"..."`) to feed the value of the variable `var` into the standard input of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need external tools for this, bash can do it trivially and efficiently on it's own:

```
$ someString='\n\nCreate a URL where the client can point their web browser to.  This URL should test the following IP addresses and ports for connectivity.'

$ echo "${someString//\\n/}"
Create a URL where the client can point their web browser to.  This URL should test the following IP addresses and ports for connectivity.
```